# jQuery if a link hasClass, apply a class to its parent

Tags: jquery

I've got a simple list:

```
<ol>
    <li><a href="#" class="on"> I'm on</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> I'm off</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> I'm off</a> </li>
</ol>
```

I want apply a class to the `<li>` if the `<a>` it contains has the class `on`.

IE:  I want to change from

`<li><a href="#" class="on"> I'm on</a> </li>`

to:

`<li class="active"><a href="#" class="on"> I'm on</a> </li>`

There's 100 better ways to do this using just css, but all involve refactoring a complicated slider I have setup. If I could use the `a.on` to affect its `.parent()`, I'd be all set.

Le fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/saltcod/GY2qP/1/

Comment: The CSS in your fiddle is missing a `}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were settings the parent of all anchors inside lis to be yellow if any anchor ahd the class on.

Use this instead:

```
//remove on states for all nav links
$("li a").removeClass("on");
$("li").removeClass("yellow");

//add on state to selected nav link
$(this).addClass("on");
$(this).parent().addClass('yellow');
```

[**Updated JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GY2qP/6/)

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
$('a.on').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/rdrsd/](http://jsfiddle.net/rdrsd/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('a').hasClass('on')) {
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle, change your code to

```
if ( $(this).hasClass('on') ){ 
    $(this).parent().addClass('yellow'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should do the trick,

**Edit:** Simplified your code...

```
$("li a").click(function(e){

    //stop browser default
    e.preventDefault();

    //remove on states for all nav links
    $("li a").removeClass("on").parent().removeClass('yellow');

    //add on state to selected nav link
    $(this).addClass("on").parent().addClass('yellow');

});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/GY2qP/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the line

```
$('li a').parent().addClass('yellow');
```

with

```
$(this).parent().addClass('yellow');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
var $lis = $('li'),
    $links = $lis.children('a');

$links.click(function(e){

    //stop browser default
    e.preventDefault();

    var $this = $(this);

    //remove on states for all nav links
    $links.removeClass('on');
    $lis.removeClass('yellow');

    //add on state to selected nav link
    $this.addClass("on").parent().addClass('yellow');
});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/sQckP/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li a").click(function(e){

  //stop browser default
  e.preventDefault();

  //remove on states for all nav links
  $("li").removeClass("yellow");
  $("li a").removeClass("on");

  //add on state to selected nav link
  $(this).addClass("on");
  $(this).parent().addClass('yellow');

});
```

A fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GY2qP/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Set the `class="yellow"` on the `li` if you click on the `a`. Don't give an extra `class="on"` to the `a`.

http://jsfiddle.net/HerrSerker/GY2qP/8/

```
$("li a")
    .click(function(e) {
        //stop browser default
        e.preventDefault();

        //remove on states for all nav links
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("yellow");

        //add on state to selected nav link
        $(this).parent().addClass("yellow");

    })
.end();
```

### ​

```
p {margin: 1em 0; } strong {font-weight: bold }

ol {width: 125px;background: #eee; }

li { padding: 10px; border-bottom: 1px solid;}

.yellow a {background: #ccc; }

.yellow {background: #ffff00;}
​
```

---

```
<ol>
    <li class="yellow"><a href="#"> A</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> B</a> </li>
    <li><a href="#"> C</a> </li>
</ol>
```